# How do you calculate thrust produced by a rocket engine?

Tags: engines, thrust, rocket-equation, amateur-rocketry

I was planning on building a water-powered rocket. I also wanted to know how high my rocket might go. Could someone help me figure out, how to calculate thrust produced by a rocket engine?

Comment: By water powered, do you mean a rocket where compressed air pushes water out? Start by calculating the energy in the compressed air at the instant of launch. A *fraction* of this potential energy is what is present in the rocket when it reaches peak altitude. There will be a lot of losses also which will bring down the peak altitude from the value arrived at using the energy method.

Comment: @AJN Yes, a rocket in  which compressed air pushes it water out. Can you please use some numericals in the rocket equation? Thank you in advance

Comment: You have provided no numerical data in your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the mass flow rate q and the exhaust velocity v, the thrust f is the product of q and v.

If the engine is running in a test stand, measurement of the thrust might be easier than to measure both mass flow rate and exhaust velocity.

For the measurement of thrust look at this [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/22364/how-can-i-measure-the-thrust-of-a-model-rocket-and-get-other-statistics?rq=1).