# Thrust in Newtons to specific impulse

Tags: propulsion

I'm almost certainly missing something here so I'd be grateful if someone could explain but how do I convert thrust in newtons to specific impulse?

thanks.

Comment: there is also some helpful information in answers to [How do I get Specific impulse in (s) from (N * s/kg)?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25370/12102) and [What is total impulse?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20807/12102)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't directly convert them; they're two different measures. As Organic Marble points out, thrust is loosely analogous to a car's horsepower; specific impulse is loosely analogous to a car's gas mileage.

Thrust in newtons is equal to the *propellant mass exhaust flow rate* in kg/s times the specific impulse in N·s/kg (which is dimensionally equivalent to m/s), however.

You more often see specific impulse given in seconds; multiply seconds by [9.81](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravity) to get N·s/kg. Note that the use of standard gravity as a conversion factor does not mean that specific impulse changes under different gravity. Rather, it's required because of the historical conflation of "pound" as both a unit of force and a unit of mass. Specific impulse in seconds is really "pounds-force seconds per pound-mass" which has the same dimensionality as N·s/kg.